# Using the same font size or width px in Wicked pdf shows differently in MAC and Ubuntu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, wicked-pdf

I use wicked pdf for generating pdf in my ruby on rails project. I set CSS in the part in `show.pdf.erb`.

I use the same font-size px for p or same width or height px, however, in Ubuntu system it's much bigger than in the Mac system. I set the same `page_size: 'Letter'`, may I know how to solve this? Is that because of the resolution or retina of Mac? Even if I use em or % for the font size or width, it still looks very different in Mac and Ubuntu. I want to make a business card size div with some content inside no matter people use Mac to open and print the pdf or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wickedpdf on different platforms renders differently because of:

1. system fonts are different (this can be somewhat fixed by using custom web fonts)
2. systems have different DPI settings (this affects sizing the most, but can be tuned)
3. different font renderers and smoothing

For exact sizes it's better to use corresponding markup - with `cm` or `in` units.
Also for more control over resulting pdf - you may want to eliminate intermediate html render and use direct pdf rendering with something like `prawn pdf`